# Where have my commits gone?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a repository log like this...

```
<randomSha> 5
<randomSha> 4
<randomSha> 3
<randomSha> 2
<randomSha> 1
```

I wanted to modify a file in '3' and so...

1. I did `git rebase --interactive <shaOf1>`
2. then I opened up vi and had to set item 3 to 'edit'
3. then I modified a file
4. then `git commit --all --amend --no-edit`
5. then I got a merge problem at item 4 so I merged in
6. then `git rebase --continue`

I repeated the bottom two steps until I got to item 5.

It all worked but when I did a `git log --oneline` I now only have these

```
<randomSha> 3
<randomSha> 2
<randomSha> 1
```

Where have 4 and 5 gone?

UPDATE : someone suggested I check the reflog which gave me this...

```
fa755b2 HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
fa755b2 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): 3
55ff2f2 HEAD@{2}: cherry-pick: fast-forward
89a44a2 HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (start): checkout eea7ec2^
5149153 HEAD@{4}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
5149153 HEAD@{5}: rebase -i (start): checkout 5149153^
5149153 HEAD@{6}: commit: 5
8eab00c HEAD@{7}: commit: 4
55ff2f2 HEAD@{8}: commit: 3
89a44a2 HEAD@{9}: commit: 2
eea7ec2 HEAD@{10}: commit: 1
b5ae9d7 HEAD@{11}: commit (initial): initial
```

Does anyone know where 4 and 5 went? I get a bit lost around the first checkout...

Comment: A linear list of commits from the log is not enough to determine what happened; you'd need to look at the commit graph as it was before the rebase. Be aware that, by default, `git rebase` does not reconstruct merge commits; the "missing" commits may have been merge commits.

Comment: You can try to restore to your old commit `5` and then check the changes that you produced with `commit (amend): 5` by `git show fa755b2` and reapply them to your repo.